# Android RecyclerView make whole item focus with focusable sub layout

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-recyclerview, focusable

I have a RecyclerView looks like the below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmJnv.png)

The circle is in a LinearLayout which has a onClickListener.When I click the circler,the behaviour is what is I expected.

The convertView of RecyclerView has set a onClickListener.When click the item of the RecyclerView the behaviour is what I don't expect for.**The extected behaviour is the whole item is focused with hightlight.But the black around the circle is not focused.**

I have searched this for a long time but got nothing.
How can I sovled it ?

This is the item layout for the RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/action_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/FormFont"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_status"
        android:background="@drawable/action_color"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/status_progressbar"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/switch_retry"
            android:text="@string/retry"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        style="@style/FormFont"
        android:id="@+id/temperature"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/FormFont"
        android:id="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/action_color"
        android:id="@+id/parent_mode"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mode"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="定时模式"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/mode_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <CheckBox
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_right_arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_spot,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

*The @drawable/action_color.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorLightGray"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorLightGray"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/colorLightGray"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

*When do not set onClickListener for statusParent(The LinearLayout wrapped the circle image,the statusParent LinearLayout would be highlight when click on the item.*
I think it's the statusParent is clickable, so it wouldn't be highlight.

```
//       viewHolder.statusParent is the LinearLayout of the Id R.id.status_parent.

//        viewHolder.statusParent.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: do you want whole row to be selected ?

Comment: The row do not need to be selected.Just  highlight when it is clicked on. When click on the area outside the circle,I want the whole row is highlight.But when click on the circle,I want only the circle is highlight.

Comment: why don't you wrap them all in single `LinearLayout` then ?

Comment: I have edited the question.The LinearLayout is used for the RecyclerView Adapter to create ViewHolder.

Comment: yah I know that but your layout is not wrapped in single element, Make it wrap with single element..

Comment: Yes,they are in a single LinearLayout.I make paste error.I have edited it.

Comment: What about adding `android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"` in parent element ?

Comment: I have post the action_color.xml.I think it's the same as list_selector_background.

Comment: did you try adding that inside imageView too... where it's not highlighted .

Answer (score 0):

Just create PressLinearLayout extends LinearLayout and override the **dispatchSetPressed** method.All right.

```
public class PressLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public PressLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PressLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PressLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchSetPressed(boolean pressed) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
                child.setPressed(pressed);
        }
    }
}
```